# WPF - Listbox scrolling when an item is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, scrollviewer

Currently, I have a `ListBox` which is used to carry out a drag/drop operation. While this does work an error has occurred where if an item in the list is selected, then the user cannot use the vertical scrollbar with their cursor clicking on it. The user can only move this scrollbar using a mouse wheel.

From what I understand, I think it tries to count the scrollbar as a `SelectedItem` which is maybe why it cannot move properly, but I'm still unsure as to why this is occurring.. Below is the relevant code, any help on solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

### XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="WriteListBox"
           Height="326"
           Width="190"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Margin="428,25,0,0"
           ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
           ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
           PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
           PreviewMouseMove="ListBox_PreviewMouseMove"
           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ModelVariableWriteTemplate}" />
```

### Code-Behind

```
private void ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.mousePoint = e.GetPosition(null);
}

private void ListBox_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point newPoint = e.GetPosition(null);
    Vector diff = this.mousePoint - newPoint;

    ListBox listBox = sender as ListBox;
    var listBoxItem = listBox.SelectedItem;

    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        ///Drag/Drop stuff here.
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your ItemTemplate here. May be the itemtemplate overlapped with scrollviewer, lets have a look at this too

Comment: The `ItemTemplate` currently does not deal with any drag/drop operations. All it does is filter items from a collection stored within my viewmodel. See answer here - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191417/filtering-an-observablecollection-to-multiple-list-boxes)

Answer (score 3):

The ScrollViewer is part of the ListBox, which is the sending object for ListBox_PreviewMouseMove. I think that making the ListBoxItem the sender, rather than the ListBox, should remove the ScrollViewer from that event.

Comment: Or he could check which `Type` `e.OriginalSource` is and act upon that, but your solution is probably better when it comes to performance.

Comment: To elaborate on this answer: You can attach the mouse events to each individual `ListBoxItem` instead of the whole `ListBox` by setting `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle`. See this answer to a similar question for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235496/listbox-previewmouseleftbuttondown-problems-with-datatemplate/3237159#3237159

Comment: @goobering If I were to implement this, what would I use as my `dragSource` in my `DoDragDrop` method? Currently it's set to the `listBox` set in the `ListBox_PreviewMouseMove` method.

Comment: @Staeff I have tried this by just having an if() & else if() checking for a `Thumb` type and unselecting all items if the scrollbar is selected. Works for now.

Comment: Keep the ListBox as the drag source, but put the PreviewMouseMove event on the ListBoxItem.